# Code coverage for cancel button(pagereference)

Tags: unit-test

I am unable to get code coverage for Cancel button(which resets the entire page).

Cancel Button:

```
public PageReference Cancel(){
    PageReference pg = new PageReference(System.currentPageReference().getURL());
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg;
}
```

Test:

```
PageReference pageRefc = Page.Vendor_Support_Form;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRefc);
apexpages.currentpage().getParameters().put('URL','www.test.com');
```

Comment: Please do not just delete old questions and re-ask them. Take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask].

Comment: You just have to call cancel method using instance of the controller, where exactly are you facing the challenge

Comment: Hi Rahul, tried it but still throwing the error "System.NullPointerException: Argument 1 cannot be null"

Comment: @Laxman It would help if you provided more context (more of your controller, more of your unit test(s)). Right now, there's not enough information for us to really be of much help. Rahul's comment nails the problem exactly. If you've tried Rahul's suggestion, and are running into errors, you should [edit] your question to include what you've tried, the whole text of the error message **verbaitm**, and preferably add some indication as to which line of your provided code is the one causing the error. A good position to take here is "when in doubt, include more details".